# How to execute two commands in one for loop of .bat?

Tags: image, for-loop, image-processing, cmd

I have written a short .bat file that converts images via a few programs that I have.  Unfortunately, the folders of images that I have are very large, and as it stands now, this program makes a .png, but also leaves a .pgm.  This causes the program to stop because the folder runs out of memory.

The .bat now is:

```
mogrify -format pgm ephemeral:*.png
forfiles /M *.pgm /C "cmd /c for %%s in (@fname) do DebayerGPU.exe -demosaic DFPD_R -GPU -pattern GRBG -i %%s.pgm -o %%s.ppm"
mogrify -format png ephemeral:*.ppm
```

I have tried adding "del @fname.pgm" in its own quotes, and I have tried putting () around the command after the do statement, putting a ; and adding del @fname.pgm.  But that also doesn't work.

The second line of the program converts a .pgm to a .ppm and leaves the .pgm there.  My goal is to add another command/line that deletes the .pgm after it is converted to a .ppm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `&&` instead of `;`.

But currently I cannot even see why this uses both `forfiles` and `for`. There should be no reason for that. If I understand it correctly, you could just use

```
mogrify -format pgm ephemeral:*.png
for %%s in (*.pgm) do (
  DebayerGPU.exe -demosaic DFPD_R -GPU -pattern GRBG -i %%s -o %%~ns.ppm
  del %%s
)
mogrify -format png ephemeral:*.ppm
```

Comment: thanks!  It uses forfiles and for because the DebayerGPU program interprets "@fname" as the actual filename if I just use forfiles.